# How to properly update a field in JTable with a date data type in mySql?

Tags: java, sql

Here's my code and it compiles with no errors, but nothing seems to change when I edit a cell

```
public void setValueAt(Object v, int r, int c)
    {
        try {
            rs.absolute(r+1);
            rs.updateString(c+1, String.valueOf(v));
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyModel2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I can successfully edit the value by double-clicking the cell but whenever I press enter, it doesn't save my input and it doesn't produce any error as well.

**EDIT**

As stated by @MadProgrammer , updateString only affects the view, by simply adding the updateRow() method, the changes go directly to the database!

```
public void setValueAt(Object v, int r, int c)
    {
        try {
            rs.absolute(r+1);

           rs.updateString(c+1, String.valueOf(v));
           rs.updateRow();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyModel2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without your posting a decent attempt at a [mcve] and more information about context, this is going to be extremely difficult to answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am terribly sorry for that, but isn't that the only code needed to edit cell?

Comment: So from the JavaDocs *"Updates the designated column with a String value. The updater methods are used to update column values in the current row or the insert row. The updater methods do not update the underlying database; instead the updateRow or insertRow methods are called to update the database"*, so to update the underlying row, you need to call ResultSet#updateRow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateString-int-java.lang.String-) *"Updates the designated column with a String value. The updater methods are used to update column values in the current row or the insert row. The updater methods do not update the underlying database; instead the updateRow or insertRow methods are called to update the database"*, so to update the underlying row, you need to call [`ResultSet#updateRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateRow--)